# Monomial Basis with $>1$ variable

Tags: polynomials

In my course, one defines $B_{n, d}(x)$ as “a basis of monomials of degree at most $d$.”

I also have an example for $n=1$ :

$$
B_{1, 2}(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
x\\
x^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But I cannot find an example online of such a basis of monomials for more than 1 variable. For instance, what would $B_{2, 2}(x)$ be ? My guess would be something like

$$
B_{2, 2}(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
x_1 & x_2^2\\
x_1^2 & x_2^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But I am really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis $\;B_{2,2}(x)\;$ is the following one :

$$
B_{2, 2}(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_1x_2\\
x_1^2\\
x_2^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$